# Suppose $T:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^n, T(v)=Av$ where $A$ is a symmetric matrix, choose all correct statements

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Suppose $$T:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^n, T(v)=Av$$

where $A$  is a symmetric  matrix, choose all correct statements

1. Any two eigenvectors of $T$ are orthogonal
2. eigenvectors corresponding to distinct eigenvalues of T is orhtogonal
3. Any eigenbasis of $T$ is orthonormal
4. $T$  has an orthonormal eigenbasis

My attempt :

I know that If A is an $n \times n$ symmetric matrix, then any two eigenvectors that come from distinct eigenvalues are orthogonal.so 2 is correct

and Using the SPECTRAL THEOREM, we know A has an orthonormal eigenbasis so 4 is correct
can some expain 1, 3?

Comment: When could you have two non-orthogonal eigenvectors?

Comment: Take the identity matrix. Then any basis is a set of eigenvectors. No need for them to be orthogonal. You can, of course, choose an orthogonal set.

Comment: @copper.hat. i am confusing with ur statment

Comment: @JamieRadcliffe when that matrix is not symmetric

Comment: @InverseProblem I am showing that 1. is not necessarily true.